# Помощь студентам на сайте

Tags: обсуждение

Добрый день коллеги.

Несколько раз уже я замечал, что на сайте процветает культ снобизма и нелепой надменности по отношению к студентам и их учебным заданиям. А именно, постоянно учебные задания банятся с формулировкой "надо самому делать".

Все мы были студентами и такое поведение по меньшей мере странно.

В связи с этим предлагаю (как сделано на всех уважающих себя форумах) завести отдельные метки "С++ для начинающих" "Ява для начинающих" "Питон для начинающих" и так далее и там размещать учебные задания.

Если кому не интересно, тот не будет ни помогать студентам ни даже читать их вопросы.

Что касается меня, да мне нравится сортировать массивы, обращать матрицы и находить наибольшие элементы. Особенно если задание написано на украинском языке.

Спасибо.

UPD1:

[это плохой вопрос]

Вам не нравится чужой вопрос - пойдите попейте чаю. Не надо взваливать на свои хрупкие плечи задачу отделения добра от зла, она вам все равно не по силам.

UPD2:

[вряд ли стали настоящими специалистами]

Кто не станет настоящим специалистом, тот не будет работать программистом. Таким образом система саморегулируется без помощи доброхотов, назначивших себя святее Папы Римского с помощью дутого рейтинга. И уж тем более ничью нравственность не могут покачнуть отдельные метки "для начинающих", где будут жить студенты и их вопросы.

UPD3:

[Цели администрации (как я ее понимаю) - создать ресурс с быстрым поиском верного решения появившейся нестандартной проблемы, либо квалифицированной помощью в случае отсутствия готового решения и последующего его переиспользования. Некоторая база знаний по нестандартным ситуациям для квалифицированных специалистов в своей области, которые делятся друг с другом неочевидными моментами в процессе разработки и не должны тратить много времени на решение этих проблем.]

Зададим себе вопрос - какова вероятность, что крутой спец просматривает ленту вопросов именно в тот момент, когда у пользователя возникает "нестандартная проблема"? Ясно, что вероятность этого равна нулю. Поэтому ожидать, что SO станет элитным клубом для крутых с базой знаний по вопросам на уровне нобелевки не приходится. Спуститесь на землю, SO это обычный форум да еще с косым интерфейсом, так как он не поднимает отвеченные вопросы наверх обсуждения (как это положено делать), а заталкивает их в небытие.

UPD4:

[Если Вас не устраивают услуги оказываемые вам здесь совершенно безвозмездно, зачем Вы здесь?]

Меня не устраивает снобистская цензура вопросов. Вот этот вопрос останется в ленте и этот не останется решает некая клака местных самозваных гуру с дутым рейтингом. Отведите для вопросов, недостойных Вашего просвещенного внимания, отдельные метки, а сами наслаждайтесь полетом в эмпиреях. Надеюсь, что в этих эмпиреях Вы не столкнетесь с Боингом-747.

UPD5:

[Интересно, сколько % задающих элементарные вопросы и не трудящихся решить их самостоятельно поставят на вопрос метку "для начинающих" ?]

Если студенты не поставят правильную метку, то это хорошее занятие для местных бабушек на скамейках - самим перевести вопрос под метку "для начинающих" вместо того, чтобы с праведным инквизиторским гневом сжигать вопрос на костре.

UPD6:

[Лично я не собираюсь помогать закрыть зачет]

Никто Вас и не принуждает отвечать на вопрос, который вам кажется ниже Вашего достоинства. Просто не стирайте этот недостойный Вас вопрос, переведите его в специальное место. Вполне возможно, что кому-то другому этот вопрос будет вполне интересен даже при условии, что автор ничего не сделал сам а хочет получить зачет нахаляву.

Кстати, Mike, если не секрет. Объясните, как за 2 года и за 898 ответов можно получить 30,632 баллов репутации. :-)

UPD7:

["что автор ничего не сделал сам а хочет получить зачет нахаляву." желаю чтобы вам такие врачи не попадались...]

Такие врачи не работают врачами, такие программисты не работают программистами. Не надо изображать из себя борцов за всемирную нравственность, SO это не то место. Хотя бы из-за присутствия лиц с рейтингами выше всяких похвал. :-) Просто перенесите учебные вопросы под отдельную метку и будет всем щасьтя.

UPD8:

[в профиле каждого участника есть полный лог репутации, когда и за что]

Я поинтересовался несколькими узлами лога уважаемого Mike. Выяснилось, что он получает репутацию даже за сами вопросы. :-)

UPD9:

[Весьма сложно, грубо отзываясь о других участниках, убедить их в своей правоте.]

Грубо? Где Вы видели здесь грубость? Обсуждение предельно корректное. И да, я не собираюсь никого ни в чем убеждать. Сам я давно не студент и мне ЛИЧНО это как-бы вообще не нужно. Но вот что знаменитая объективность напрочь отказывает местным завсегдатаям, это факт.

UPD10:

[Ознакомьтесь: ru.stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation]

Еще на заре присутствия здесь я ознакомился с этой прокламацией всеобщего равенства, и как раз по результатам ознакомления получается, что репутацию и в 15000 и в 30000 и тем более в 70000 за 2 года получить без мухлежа никак невозможно. :-) Поэтому и возникают неприятные вопросы.

UPD11:

[Будьте дружелюбными]

Стирание чужих вопросов, какими бы соображениями высшей пользы для Вселенной они не прикрывались, это не очень дружелюбное поведение. Не нравится вам вопрос - пройдите мимо него. Наверное не убудет от десяти экзабайт мирового интернета, если там будет лежать еще и вопрос несчастного студента Вологодского политеха.

UPD12:

[15000 это всего-навсего 400 ответов с 4мя голосами "за" каждый. Ничего невероятного и неприятного.]

Если на ответ тратится 1 минута, то это явно не решение "нестандартной ситуации для квалифицированных специалистов в своей области". А если ответ требует работы, то откуда у человека берется столько времени? Кроме того, если плюсуется сам вопрос, это вызывает большие сомнения. Не столько тут гениальных вопросов. :-)

Но вобщем я не собираюсь никого ловить за рейтинг. Каждый живет как может. Но не надо мешать другим ни задавать учебные вопросы, ни отвечать на них, если такие любители есть. Повторю еще раз - есть хороший, дешевый, логичный и простой способ рашения проблемы. Для снобов, которых тошнит от студентов, надо завести метки "для начинающих" и скидывать все вопросы, которые ревнителям ритуальной программистской чистоты кажутся учебными, под эти метки.

UPD13:

[тратить силы на раскидываение метки на вопросы, в которых автор даже не потрудился нормально сформулировать проблему, никто не захотел.]

При удалении вопроса тратится столько же сил, как и при перемещении вопроса под метку "для начинающих".

Comment: Комментарии не предназначены для расширенной дискуссии; разговор [перемещён в чат](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/68574/discussion-on-question-by-pepsicoca1----).

Answer (score 16):

Только недавно было бурное обсуждение этого вопроса в чате.

Закрываются и минусуются вопросы в которых прослеживается явное желание автора, чтобы задачу решили за него, а он не напрягаясь скопипастил решение.

Т.е. если вопрос по заданию идет типа "Вот такая задачка, пробовал то-то и то-то, но не получается, подскажите, куда копать?" - это хороший вопрос, а "Вот вам задача, я над ней даже не думал, как решите - сообщите, а я пойду чаю попью" - это плохой вопрос.

> Не нравится вам вопрос - пройдите мимо него. Наверное не убудет от
>   десяти экзабайт мирового интернета, если там будет лежать еще и вопрос
>   несчастного студента Вологодского политеха.

Дело в том, что такие вопросы, к сожалению, будут провоцировать других студентов политеха действовать по той же схеме и ресурс превратится в свалку абсолютно бесполезного контента. Почитайте о [теории разбитых окон](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A2%D0%B5%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%B8%D1%8F_%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B7%D0%B1%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%8B%D1%85_%D0%BE%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BD).

Comment: Кстати [почти про чай](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/33408086#33408086)  %)

Comment: @АлексейШиманский, честно говоря, вопрос там вполне себе адекватный. О каком коде вообще шла речь?

Comment: @vp_arth не помню откуда ноги растут. возможно кто-то советовал открыть IDE, создать списки,  вывести в консоль и посмотреть результат.

Comment: По поводу ответа - мотивация автора не должна быть критерием оценки. Нужно оценивать вопрос с точки зрения: "Является ли он крупицей знаний, достойной пополнить базу знаний SO? Скольким людям помимо автора он будет полезен?" С другой стороны плохая мотивация почти всегда коррелирует с плохим качеством.

Comment: @vp_arth тут такое дело. Действительно хорошая задача вряд ли будет подана в "лентяйском" стиле, так как до таких задач надо доучиться. Подавляющее большинство "плохих" вопросов относятся к конкретной реализации совсем простых и базовых вещей, что может помочь, только тем, кому задана ровно та-же задача с ровно теми же граничными условиями.

Answer (score 12):

На самом деле, хороший вопрос. Есть вполне конкретные причины, по которым у нас нет отдельной метки, и запрещены копипасты задач из учебника.

Почему нет отдельной метки: Отдельная метка была. Ее ставили добросовестные студенты, которые задавали вопросы, возникшие в процессе решения задачи. Для таких вопросов метка ничего полезного не добавляла. Халявщики, копипастившие задачи прямо из учебника, метку, естественно, не ставили.

---

Почему вопросы из задачников, без попыток решения, закрываются? Потому что на SO есть вполне [конкретный онтопик](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) и вполне [конкретные требования к вопросам](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask). Задачки сносят за то, что они совсем не вписываются в

> практические вопросы, основанные на реальных проблемах ... [программирования: коду, алгоритмам, реализации алгоритмов на определенных языках программирования;]

Нравственность, борьба и прочее не имеет к этому никакого отношения. SO - это не закрытый клуб. Наоборот, SO - это открытое сообщество. Но для программистов. А не для врачей, пивоваров, пилотов реактивных истребителей и прочих уважаемых профессий. Если человек не программист, и не пытается им стать - ну извините, он немного не вписывается в местное общество. Даже если он оставляет на сайте следы в виде каких-то задач, которые его заставляют решать явно против его воли.

---

Много вопросов в одном, так что дальше по отдельным цитатам:

> SO это обычный форум да еще с косым интерфейсом, так как он не поднимает отвеченные вопросы наверх обсуждения (как это положено делать), а заталкивает их в небытие

Честно, не понимаю - почему SO должен поднимать наверх отвеченные вопросы? SO поднимает наверх *неотвеченные* вопросы. Не все вопросы получают ответы мгновенно. И не будут получать. Медианное время получения ответа - несколько *дней*, а не минут. Время появления ответа для 95% отвеченных вопросов - пару *месяцев*.

Если у вас есть какие-то соображения, по которым отвеченные вопросы стоит еще как-то дополнительно поднимать (они и так поднимаются, в момент появления ответа) - пожалуйста, оформите их отдельным постом на мете.

Comment: Вопрос и все его двенадцать апдейтов...

Comment: [SO поднимает наверх неотвеченные вопросы.]

Хоть это и не имеет отношения к теме обсуждения студенческих вопросов, все-таки интересно. Где это написано, что SO поднимает наверх неотвеченные вопросы? И через сколько времени это происходит?

Comment: @pepsicoca1 в профиле участника, который занимается подъемом: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/-1/%D0%94%D1%83%D1%85-%D1%81%D0%BE%D0%BE%D0%B1%D1%89%D0%B5%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B2%D0%B0?tab=profile

Comment: [случайным образом раз в час] Лотерея? А почему не сделать так, как со времен Минина и Пожарского было заведено на форумах - каждый ответ (и комментарий естественно) поднимает вопрос в обсуждении. Конец реплик означает исчерпанность коллективного разума по данной проблеме "здесь и сейчас".

Comment: @pepsicoca1 не знаю что вы подразумеваете под "поднимать в обсуждении". каждый новый ответ понимает вопрос на главной странице. комментарий - не поднимает (и, imho, не должен)

Comment: @pepsicoca1 у меня сложилось впечатление, что вы не разобрались в особенностях движка и в особенностях траффика (почти все приходят из гугла прямо в вопрос с ответами, вне зависимости от того, высоко ли он на главной) - и делаете из этого какие-то выводы. Вы даже голосованием на сайте не пользуетесь. Попробуйте активно поучаствовать, поотвечать на вопросы (или хотя бы позадавать их), поголосовать за то, что вам нравится - и многие вопросы отпадут. заодно узнаете, почему "SO - не форум".

Comment: В ленте же есть табы - Новые, Текущие, в текущих соортировка по дате изменений/ответам.

Comment: "нет отдельной метки" - уже возродилась
 https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/homework

Comment: @VadimTagil fixed

Comment: Всё, что я сам хотел бы написать в ответ на этот вопрос, уже есть в вашем ответе.

Answer (score 5):

Вопрос сам по себе неплох.

Мне не очень нравится стиль обсуждения: автор уже внёс 12 правок и очень сложно следить за мыслью, перемещаясь туда-сюда. У меня такой стиль ассоциируется с шапкозакидательством, я бы предложил переместиться в чат и обсудить там какие-то боковые ответвления от главного вопроса.

Так же я хотел бы порекомендовать топикстартеру не принимать близко к сердцу минуса на вопросе: на мете принято голосование "мне нравится это предложение" и "я не согласен с этим предложением" выполнять при помощи апвоут/даунвоут вопроса. Тут ничего личного нет: оценивается не автор сам по себе, а предложение.

Что же до самого вопроса.

Во-первых, хочу заметить следующее. Видите ли, любое сообщество расколото на большинство и на меньшинство. И по данному конкретному вопросу (не знаю, как по остальным) вы идёте против мнения большинства. Поэтому гипотетически можно было бы учесть ваше стремление отвечать на домашние задания, а остальные бы проходили мимо, либо минусовали вопрос -- но нужно придумать какой-то способ, который бы не создавал дополнительную нагрузку на большинство. Вы, например, говорите "пусть большинство создаёт метку" -- а вообще, по факту решение должно быть прямо противоположным: тот, кто хочет спасти вопрос должен навесить на вопрос метку "учебное задание" и дать ответ в течение часа. Понимаете логику?

Во-вторых, мы в своём опыте можем ориентироваться на опыт большого stackoverflow. В принципе, можно показать, что ваша инциатива при её реализации неизбежно скатится к какому-то негативному результату. (Это больше про вариант "создать отдельное сообщество по решению домашней работы")

Comment: Меня очень дружелюбно забанили здесь. Так что остаюсь при своем мнении.

Comment: @pepsicoca1 за нарушение правил?

Comment: Не знаю за что. Пишет "сообщение заблокировано" без дальнейших объяснений. :-)

Comment: @Nofate видимо закрытие вопроса кто-то считает баном и оскорблением

Comment: @pepsicoca1 вы в текущем вопросе: обсуждали конкретных участников, намекали на их нечестность, грубо отзывались о широкой группе участников, "шумели" множеством правок своего вопроса. У нас так не принято. Так что аппелировать к дружелюбию поздно.

Comment: [закрытие вопроса кто-то считает баном] Интересно, а чем же это считать? Кого вообще волнует, сколько времени и о чем идет обсуждение? Тут же по делу общаются, а не как ограбить банк обсуждают. Определенно, на этом сайте переизбыток явный моралистов в самом плохом значении этого слова.

Comment: @pepsicoca1 заблокированы не вы, а вопрос. И как я понимаю, это из-за того, что вопрос изначально был задан не здесь, а здесь был закрыт, что расценивается как "безуспешный перенос" (и автоматика предполагает, что здесь этому вопросу тоже не место; что не так, но без модераторского вмешательства систему не переубедить). Теперь его нельзя править и комментировать, и голосовать за/против него тоже. Но все остальные виды активности вам по-прежнему должны быть доступны. А если б вы изначально задали вопрос на Мете, было бы только закрытие, и нельзя было б только оставлять к вопросу новые ответы.

Comment: @pepsicoca1 может быть, наше сообщество с нашими правилами вам не подходит.

Comment: @pepsicoca1 ознакомьтесь с правилами ресурса. узнайте **Как правильно**  задавать вопросы или предложения. То, что вы их не знаете и они не такие, к которым вы лично привыкли и здесь их нет - проблема **не данного сообщества**

Comment: @pepsicoca1 Прочитайте мою формулировку причины закрытия вопроса и скажите, что вы находите в ней неуважительного и оскорбляющего: Данный вопрос следует закрыть, потому что вопрос постоянно правится (уже более десятка апдейтов!) и эти многократные обновления похожи на режим "чата". Это не похоже на хорошо проработанный вопрос, приходите в чат, побеседуем там, ладно?

Comment: @pepsicoca1 я переоткрыл вопрос — он явно относится к обсуждению сайта.

Comment: @NickVolynkin ну вот, своим переоткрытием убрали баннер, в котором текст был плохо адаптирован. Теперь придется снова закрывать.